# CSGO Drops, can anyone update me on the current csgo 2020 drop rates?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Any CSGO items drops you can get after level 21 or prime status? What can you get? Are stickers drops possible?

Comment: Yeah, this is outdated from 6 yrs ago.

Comment: @BitES Check the accepted answer (with 0 score).  That seems to fit better with how the game works (or at least how it worked a few months ago last time I played).